Why does nobody talk about the fact that linear phase FIRs are not so linear?
I noticed that in supposedly linear phase FIR filters, the phase is only linear within the main lobe. I have not found anyone else discussing the fact that the phase inverts at every null point between lobes. Maybe this fact is inconsequential if you are dealing with a filter that has very high stopband attenuation. However, it seems like for some types of filters, specifically ones that do not have high stopband attenuation, this would result in noticeable phase distortion from your linear phase filter. So my two questions are, why is this not mentioned more, and can this be avoided somehow?
Edit: I found the following document which seems to be referring to the same thing that I was. How linear phase filters can still cause phase distortion

Imagine the same impulse response but advanced in time enough to be a zero-phase filter.  Then what you have is no delay, at all frequencies.  But, in the stopband, there will be lobes in the frequency response that the real gain passes through zero and becomes negative in polarity.  You can interpret that as 180° phase shift with a positive gain or you can interpret that as 0° phase shift with a negative gain.  Both interpretations are mathematically equivalent.

Excellent explanation @robertbristow-johnson - good enough to be the answer

I wouldn't call that an answer to either of my questions, it more like an elaboration on what I am describing.

I thought he captured really well why it has no phase distortion, since it is simply a perfectly delayed copy of a zero phase result (if a filter is zero phase, then there is no change to phase whatsoever). This is why we like linear phase filters, as far as phase performance goes, they are no different than a perfect cable as I detail here in case you haven't seen this explanation: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/why-is-a-linear-phase-important/31732#31732

@DanBoschen The 180 degree phase inversions (or negative gain—it doesn't matter how you interpret it) is not linear. That's the point of my question. I'm not sure you understood my question.

@Chris_F I understood your question but not your concern. If your signal is completely in the passband, then the 0/180 degree invesion in the stopband is completely inconsequential (given the stop band is not part of your signal). Did you have a particular filter application in mind where you need a workaround other than simply increasing your stopband attenuation if that was the issue (more taps)? Forgive my questions, I'm just having trouble seeing the practical value  (not at all to say that there isn't one! If there was a specific example that extra detail could be helpful to your point)

@DanBoschen I am not working on anything right now where this is an issue. It's just an idea that occurred to me, and it seems odd that I have not heard it discussed, ever. An example could perhaps be something like a box filter. Such a filter hardly has a stopband at all, so the phase distortion will be much more obvious.

See my answer here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/95133/21048  The Group Delay is constant over all frequencies except where mag=0 regardless of 0/180 phase reversal outside of the filter passband which is the prime consideration for using "Linear phase". If the 0/180 degree reversal is a concern for your particular signal, then you are using the wrong filter (you wouldn't "compensate" for this when you can just use a different filter altogether--- I'd need to see a use case where that wouldn't apply to be able to comment further, hope that helps).

You can get rid of (or avoid) negative gain frequencies in a linear phase filter by adding back enough of the original signal, with the same delay as the filter, to negate the maximum negative gain.  Thus the lowest gain will end up being zero gain (which has an indeterminate phase), rather than negative  gain (which can be (mis)interpreted as positive gain with a 180 degree phase shift).

I believe the reason why this phenomenon is hardly mentioned anywhere is that in the majority of applications it's irrelevant. As you've pointed out yourself, frequency-selective filters with a high stopband attenuation will invert the input only in parts of the stopband where the attenuation is high, and we're not interested in these signal components anyway.
In the case of notch filters or, more generally, bandstop filters, the different passbands may be inverted with respect to each other, depending on the number of frequency response zeros between the bands. In most cases, this is again irrelevant. E.g., in audio applications, inversion of the signal doesn't matter as long as we don't mix different signals.
Now let's finally get to applications where such a sign inversion could matter. I don't know of any, but the example shown in the document you linked to might be one. However, I believe it's really a rather simple problem to solve, as long as we're aware of it. We know that each frequency zero inverts the input signal, and if needed we can easily correct for that, as was done in that document.
Theoretically, we can get rid of the sign inversion by increasing the multiplicity of the offending frequency response zeros. E.g., a single zero becomes a double zero, etc. This will of course also change the magnitude of the frequency response, and in some cases such a change may be undesirable. E.g., if a sharp notch is required, replacing a single zero with a double zero (hence broadening the notch) may not be an option.
If we consider general bandstop filters (not notch filters), we could make sure that the number of zeros between the bands is even if we're interested in avoiding sign inversion between the two passbands.
In sum, the phenomenon you describe is hardly mentioned because in most applications it doesn't seem to be a problem. Also, most textbooks describe phase linearity in the context of frequency-selective filters (with a single passband), for which the phase in the stopbands is irrelevant. I agree that there might be cases where signal inversion in different bands could be a problem, mainly for sinusoidal signals, but in these cases the phase inversion can be taken into account quite easily.

1.- Not all FIR filters are linear
For a filter to be linear in phase
the frequency response of that filter has to have

CONSTANT GROUP DELAY

meaning frequency response phase has CONSTANT SLOPE

frequency response amplitude has to be real

no imaginary values
This conditions translate to, are the same as :
filter time coefficients being symmetric around the central point of such TIME coefficients.
As concisely explained in Van Veen presentation 1, with the above constrains there are 4 possible types of FIR LINEAR filters :

Type-I (M even)

Type-I (M odd)

Type-II  (M even)

Type-II (M odd)


M being the amount of filter time coefficients.
Also recommended reading
LINEAR PHASE FIR-FILTERS 3
References
1 Linear Phase FIR Filters
author: Barry Van Veen
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVOkWcknvc4&ab_channel=BarryVanVeen
2 LINEAR-PHASE FIR FILTERS
NYU
https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/EL713/zoom/linphase.pdf

This is not an answer to the question asked.


Linear does not mean positive phase, as assumed in the question by line 'the phase is only linear within the main lobe ... the phase inverts (sign?) at every null point between lobes'. Linear is about the shape  slope not the sign. Linear means the slope is constant.



Then in ' .. ones (filters) that do not have high stopband attenuation, this would result in noticeable phase distortion ' . As pointed out by Dan's comment : A high attenuation im passband does not mean whether the phase is or is mot linear. You can have high distortion with very low or very high distortion im passband and at the same time the filter could be highly linear in both pass and stop bands. Because the distortion may come from an already distorted input  signal.



Please supply the filter or group of filters you are talking about in your question. At least supply a reference or specific type of filter. Because without a single line of code, or the filter, or a reference to a filter or type of filter, every one who has read so far this question has understood that the concept of phase linearity has to be clarified.


which is why I supplied the definition of linear phase in the context of signal filtering.

Please supply the signal processing system, a reference to it, some MATLAB (or Python) lines you are using that are currently inducing to the above mentioned erroneous understandings pointer out in these comments that solely aim at helping you to solve this question.

Found after the fact: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Filter_Wizard_34_How_linear_phase_filters_can_still_cause_phase_distortion-Article-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7ddc01d7017ddd08870b5bec

if you edit your question and include this document in your question readers will not have to scroll down all comments to read it.
